# MutableLiveData: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread from Coroutine

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to trigger an update on LiveData from a coroutine:

```
object AddressList: MutableLiveData<List<Address>>()
fun getAddressesLiveData(): LiveData<List<Address>> {
    AddressList.value = listOf()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        AddressList.value = getAddressList()
    }
    return AddressList
}
```

but I get the following error:

> IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread

Is there a way to make it work with coroutines?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use postValue?

Comment: @RedDeckWins. No, I just didn't take it into account but it is definitely the way to update MutableLiveData from a coroutine.

Answer (score 414, accepted):

Use `liveData.postValue(value)` instead of `liveData.value = value`. It called asynchronous.

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#postValue(T)):

> **postValue** - Posts a task to a main thread to set the given value.

Answer (score 28):

You can do one of the following :

```
object AddressList: MutableLiveData<List<Address>>()
fun getAddressesLiveData(): LiveData<List<Address>> {
    AddressList.value = listOf()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        AddressList.postValue(getAddressList())
    }

return AddressList
}
```

or

```
fun getAddressesLiveData(): LiveData<List<Address>> {
    AddressList.value = listOf()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val adresses = getAddressList()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            AddressList.value = adresses
        }
    }
    return AddressList
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think this is the perfect `postValue()` usage scenario. There is no need to force Main Thread context.

Comment: Read the documentation for `GlobalScope`. Avoid using `GlobalScope`.

Answer (score 8):

I just figured out that it's possible by using `withContext(Dispatchers.Main){}`:

```
object AddressList: MutableLiveData<List<Address>>()
fun getAddressesLiveData(): LiveData<List<Address>> {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){ AddressList.value = getAddressList() }
    }
    return AddressList
}
```

Comment: Don't call `getAdresseList()` inside the `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` block because this will be run on the main thread.
Call it outside so it's properly dispatched by `Dispatchers.Default` and use only the result on the main thread

Comment: You just literally return your heavy task to run in UI thread

Comment: Avoid using `GlobalScope`. https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#global-scope

Answer (score 6):

Although others have pointed out that, in this case, the library provides its own method to post an operation to the main thread, coroutines provide a general solution that works regardless of a given library's functionality.

The first step is to stop using `GlobalScope` for background jobs, doing this will lead to leaks where your activity, or scheduled job, or whatever unit of work you invoke this from, may get destroyed, and yet your job will continue in the background and even submit its results to the main thread. Here's what the [official documentation on `GlobalScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) states:

> Application code usually should use application-defined CoroutineScope, using async or launch on the instance of GlobalScope is highly discouraged.

You should define your own coroutine scope and its `coroutineContext` property should contain `Dispatchers.Main` as the dispatcher. Furthermore, the whole pattern of launching jobs within a function call and returning `LiveData` (which is basically another kind of `Future`), isn't the most convenient way to use coroutines. Instead you should have

```
suspend fun getAddresses() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { getAddressList() }
```

and at the call site you should `launch` a coroutine, within which you can now freely call `getAddresses()` as if it was a blocking method and get the addresses directly as a return value.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to updated UI by using **Coroutines**, there are 2 ways to achieve this

**GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main):**

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    delay(1000)     // 1 sec delay
    // call to UI thread
}
```

And if you want some work to be done in background but after that you want to **update UI**, this can be achieved by the following:

**withContext(Dispatchers.Main)**

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    delay(1000)     // 1 sec delay

    // do some background task

    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            // call to UI thread
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `GlobalScope`. https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#global-scope

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to add **Dispatchers.Main** to the launch arguments and it worked fine:

```
 val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    delay(1500)
                    search(query)
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Answer from @Amir Hossein Ghasemi is good. Just to add to it.

**liveData.value = value** is used to update the value of a LiveData only on the main thread. Usually used for RxJava

Whereas **liveData.postValue(value)** you can call it from any thread, including the main thread and background threads (asynchronous). Usually used for coroutines

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this error when I called a coroutine inside runBlockingTest for a test case

```
TestCoroutineRule().runBlockingTest {

}
```

I got it fixed by adding the instantExecutorRule as a class member

```
@get:Rule
val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me for updating livedata from thread:

```
 val adresses = getAddressList()
 GlobalScope.launch {
     messages.postValue(adresses)
 }
```